# Override virtual function with existing function

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let me first say this is **a purely academic question**, since what I want to do can be better accomplished with multiple layers of inheritance.

That said, I wonder if it's possible to override a virtual function with an existing function without writing a wrapper or adding any inheritance layers.  Code:

```
int myfunc2() { return 2; }

class Parent {
 public:
  virtual int myfunc() { return 0; }
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
 public:
  int myfunc() override { return 1; }
};

class Child2 : public Parent {
 public:
  // There a way to do this?
  // int myfunc() = myfunc2;
  // instead of this?
  int myfunc() { return myfunc2(); };
};

int main() {
  Child2 baz;
  return baz.myfunc();
}
```

I'd like to override `myfunc` in the definition of `Child2` by simply "forwarding" the declaration to the existing declaration of `myfunc2`.

Is this, or something akin to it, possible?

**Context**: I've got a bunch of child classes, some of which have identical definitions of `myfunc`, some of which do not.  A better solution is to create an intermediate child class that defines the common `myfunc` and have the pertinent children inherit from that instead.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> // There a way to do this?
> // int myfunc() = myfunc2;
> // instead of this?
> int myfunc() { return myfunc2(); };
> ```

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem.

A non-static member function accepts one more implicit parameter: pointer to the object itself. While a stand-alone function does not have such a parameter, For example you may not use the keyword `this` or member access syntax inside the definition of a stand alone function.